# Cannot see wireless device Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, networkmanager

I am unable to see any wireless devices on my ThinkPad P53. I am able to connect to the internet via ethernet.. I have run the attached shell script provided here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 Below is the output.

Any help is appreciated!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Oct 2019 12:12 EDT -0400

Booted last: 10 Oct 2019 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

MATE (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM [8086:15bb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM [17aa:2297]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 006 Device 004: ID 17ef:3082 Lenovo 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 17ef:307f Lenovo 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 17ef:307f Lenovo 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 2109:8818 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 046d:c33b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 005 Device 008: ID 2109:8818 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 17ef:3083 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 17ef:3081 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 17ef:3080 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 17ef:3080 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56bc IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05dc:c75c Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
cfg80211              679936  1 wl
wmi                    28672  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
3: enx:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ' [IF2]> brd 
    inet 192.168.12.116/23 brd 192.168.13.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx
       valid_lft 84252sec preferred_lft 84252sec
    inet6 fe80::3b43:263a:daa4:415b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enx  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.12.1 dev enx proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx scope link metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/23 dev enx proto kernel scope link src 192.168.12.116 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root      1269     1  0 11:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        ThinkPad TBT 3 Dock
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         cdc_ether
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               CDC Ethernet Device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         ' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/0000:2d:00.0/0000:2e:02.0/0000:2f:00.0/usb6/6-2/6-2.1/6-2.1.2/6-2.1.2:2.0/net/enx
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d35e0043-f0eb-374a-820d-49ff364f7be4
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.12.116/23
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.12.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.12.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.12.0/23, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.12.245
IP4.DNS[2]:                             75.75.75.75
IP4.DNS[3]:                             75.75.76.76
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.254.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.12.245 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.12.116
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.12.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        time_offset = -14400
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.13.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       unknown_224 = FGT61E4Q16002078
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 192.168.12.1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1570808176
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.12.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       ntp_servers = 208.91.113.70 208.91.115.123 208.91.113.71 208.91.114.23
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       requested_host_name = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3b43:263a:daa4:415b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d35e0043-f0eb-374a-820d-49ff364f7be4 | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.5-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=true
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MADE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enx  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enx  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       5.0.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     B3F3EC0A086D157FE5D9591
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.330546] cdc_ether 6-2.1.2:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:2f:00.0-2.1.2, CDC Ethernet Device, ' [IF2]>
[    5.344375] cdc_ether 6-2.1.2:2.0 enx: renamed from eth0
[    6.057164] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Why did you install WICD? What else have you been trying?

Comment: I tried to user WICD instead of Network Manager to see if that was the issue, but that didn't work. I have since then removed WICD. It seems that my network card was not supported by that kernel and updating to the latest 5.1 did the trick!

Comment: WICD is never the solution and no,  you didn't removed it,  at least  not when you ran the script.