# wifi driver for Debian 10

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, intel

I'm on a HP Probook 640 G5, using Debian 10, with this hardware for wireless:

`lspci -nn`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

I'm wondering if there is a driver for Debian 10 supporting this hardware anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547224/rtl8111-8168-8411-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546196/cannot-see-wireless-device-ubuntu-mate-18-04 (same lspci information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590439/wifi-driver-for-debian-10#comment1100801_590439) by Jeff Schaller 
and the linked information about your Wi-Fi 6 AX200 card, you need at least a 5.1 kernel and a recent `firmware-iwlwifi` package.
Both are available from the backports repository.

- Follow the instructions of Stephen Kitt's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545609/332764) to upgrade your kernel 
  from `buster-backports`, the current version is 5.5.17. It won't hurt to update the firmware packages as well.
- Then install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package from backports with

  ```
  sudo apt install -t buster-backports firmware-iwlwifi
  ```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.